# Wordpress ACF: How to have a validation message that you can program?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

When I use acf_form, I can have a validation message.
In this code below:

```
<?php
acf_form_head();

    

    $args = array(
        'post_id' => 'new_post', // On va créer une nouvelle publication
        'post_title' => true,
        'new_post' => array(
            'post_type' => 'entreprise', // Enregistrer dans l'annuaire
            'post_status' => 'publish', // Enregistrer en publique
            'post_id' => 'CHR'
        ),
        'field_groups' => array( 205 ), // L'ID du post du groupe de champs
        'submit_value' => 'Create', // Intitulé du bouton
        'updated_message' => "Enterprise creation done",
        'html_updated_message'  => '<div id="message" class="acf-notice -success"><p>%s</p></div>',
         
    );

 acf_form( $args ); // Afficher le formulaire
?>
```

'Enterprise creation done' is displayed after I have pushed the button 'Create'

I 'd like the validation message contains a value from an ACF.
For example, with a ACF EnterpriseName. I' d like the message is 'Enterprise  creation done'.
I don't know how to do it.
Thanks for your help

Comment: I' d like the message is 'Enterprise  [EnterpriseName_Value] creation done'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the html_updated_message argument to pass the custom message. The argument takes a string with a placeholder '%s' which will be replaced by the actual value of the ACF field.

You can use the get_field function provided by Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) to retrieve the value of the ACF field 'EnterpriseName' and include it in the custom message.

Here's an updated example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_id' => 'new_post', 
    'post_title' => true,
    'new_post' => array(
        'post_type' => 'entreprise', 
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_id' => 'CHR'
    ),
    'field_groups' => array( 205 ), 
    'submit_value' => 'Create', 
    'updated_message' => "Enterprise creation done",
    'html_updated_message'  => '<div id="message" class="acf-notice -success"><p>Enterprise %s creation done</p></div>',
);

acf_form( $args );
```

Then, after the acf_form function call, you can retrieve the value of the 'EnterpriseName' field and replace the placeholder in the custom message:

```
$enterprise_name = get_field('EnterpriseName', 'CHR');
$args['html_updated_message'] = sprintf($args['html_updated_message'], htmlspecialchars($enterprise_name));
```

Comment: I test it and I have the message 'Enterprise Enterprise creation done creation done' and not  'Enterprise [EnterpriseName_Value] creation done creation done'

Comment: You need to change the following line of code:

$enterprise_name = get_field('EnterpriseName', 'new_post');

to:

$enterprise_name = get_field('EnterpriseName', 'CHR');

And also, change the following line of code:

$args['html_updated_message'] = sprintf($args['html_updated_message'], $enterprise_name);

to:

$args['html_updated_message'] = sprintf($args['html_updated_message'], htmlspecialchars($enterprise_name));

Comment: @kikou73 I update the code, try it